# Application install replaces Existing Application on installation

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I'm currently developing an Android Application in Android Studio 3.0. I have completed a project and install the application in the mobile phone. Next I copied the entire project and edited for further updates and when I install the updated application it replaces the existing application.

I have changed the project name in the manifest file but still the problem exists.
Please give me a solution.

Comment: add your `manifest` or code

Comment: Change your package name.

Comment: If you want to avoid this behaviour, then you need to change the ``applicationId "com.foo.bar"`` in the app's build.gradle file, as well as the ``package="com.foo.bar"`` in the AndroidManifest.xml file. However this is normal behaviour; as you don't want to have multiple installations of the same app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.yourChangedPackageNameChange"
    >

<application
        ...
        android:label="@string/changed_app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
       ........
        >
```

Change the label of your application in the manifest like this..

Answer (score 0):

An application is unique based on it package name in your case I guess you are using the same package name which is resulting in replacing your existing application.
Solution: Change the application package name in manifest but if you change it at only one place it will cause conflicts in other files. So change should reflect at all place.
Just Go to your Manifest and click on package name for example

**com.example.application**

Suppose we want to change **example** out of whole package click on it and press **shift+f6**

and then click on rename package and then give a new name.
[image]
same way change other parts of the package if you want.

Then comes the applicationId which is important in case you want to upload your application to play store otherwise it won't affect using locally.
To change go to **build.gradle** change the **applicationId** to same as package name.